# How to modify django-tables2 table visual structure?

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I started to work with `Django-tables2`. I'm trying to figure out how to modify structure of the table. As you can see, labels resp. columns are very close so it's har do read them.

I'm looking for some simple solution, for example using some `widget`.

How can I change it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this is a css issue, you can add stylesheets which alter the way you view table. eg add http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/tables-min.css ( from the amazing purecss by yahoo) to your html code and then add the `pure-table` class to you root table element.